# foreach $key variable clarification

Tags: php

I have this code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{ 

  foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $key) {
    $input = implode(",", $key);
  }
} /*end is isset $_POST['submit2'] */


echo $input;
```

it produces the error " implode(): Invalid arguments passed " when I change the implode arguments to `implode(",", $_POST['check_list'])` it works as intended.
Can someone clarify why? As far as I understand the $key variable should be the same as the $_POST['submit2'] isn't that what the as in the foreach does?

Sorry if it's a silly question, I'm self taught and sometimes details like that are hard to find online.

Comment: In your code `$key` is an individual item in `$_POST['check_list']` array each time through the loop. `implode()` takes an array not a string so just use `implode(",", $_POST['check_list'])` and no loop.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Maybe yours should be an answer pointing to the documentation of `implode`.

Comment: do you really need to implode the array every time there's an item?. Take it out of the loop

Comment: Alright thanks for the help.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks. So in my code $key is just the name of the key in the array yes?

Comment: @nbro No it shouldn't. I'm not asking about the implode function.

Comment: @Miro otherwise how am I gonna get the full contents of the array?

Comment: Version 1: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { }` Version 2: `foreach ($array as $value) { }` and the `$key` holds the key and `$value` holds the value. Your version `foreach ($array as $key) { }`  names the value variable `$key`, did u get it?

Comment: No, when using just one variable like that it is the value.  To get key and value the syntax is `as $key => $val`.  Posted an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused at several levels, so let me clarify some of them:

1. You said 'As far as I understand the $key variable should be the same as the $_POST['submit2'] isn't that what the as in the foreach does?'. The answers are NO and NO: 
   The `$key` variable outside the foreach loop will contain the last element of the array that's stored in `$_POST['check_list']`, `$_POST['submit2']` seems to be only used to check if is set and nothing else in your piece of code. What `foreach` does is to traverse any iterator variable (an array in your case) and set the current item in a variable (`$key`) in your case. So after the loop, `$key` will contain the last element of that array. For more information refer to the docs: [http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php]
2. `implode` expects the second parameter to be an array, it seems you're not providing an array, but any other type. Is the last item of `$_POST['check_list']` actually an array?
3. If you're trying to 'glue' together all items of `$_POST['check_list']`, you don't need to iterate, you just use implode on that one: `$input = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);`. Otherwise, i'm not sure what are you trying to do.

Maybe if you explain what are you trying to do, we can help better.

Comment: "If you're trying to 'glue' together all items of $_POST['check_list'] "
Exactly that. I didn't know the implode() would loop through the array without putting it in a loop. I sometimes find the PHP documentation a bit vague. Your explanation is excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach already iterates trough your values. You can either get the value and echo it from there or you can add it to another array `input` if thats what you need:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{ 

  foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $value) {
    $input[] = 'Value #'. $key .' is ' . $value;
  }
}


echo implode(",", $input);
```

Comment: I actually need to insert that string from implode() into the database, so based on your code I can do this yes? 
$data = implode(",",$input)

Comment: If that's all you need to do, without modifying the values, you don't even need the `foreach`. Just do `$data = implode("," , $_POST['check_list']);` . The `foreach` is for making changes to the array before saving to DB.

Comment: Yeah, the detail that implode() loops through the array without having to put it in a loop skipped me. It's clear now, and the foreach is much clearer now too. Sometimes the PHP documentation is a bit vague for me. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that `$_POST['check_list']` is an array if `implode()` works on it, so no need to loop to get individual items.  To `implode()` the values:

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['check_list']);
```

To `implode()` the keys:

```
echo implode(',', array_keys($_POST['check_list']));
```

`foreach()` iterates over an array to expose each item and get the individual values and optionally keys one at a time:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $value<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the detail that implode() loops through the array without having to put it in a loop skipped me. It's clear now, and the foreach is much clearer now too. Sometimes the PHP documentation is a bit vague for me. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`implode` function needs array as second argument. You are passing string value as second argument. That's why it's not working.

Comment: My question isn't about the implode function bro. I know how it works. My question is about the foreach $key